# Every time I "git push heroku master" it empties out my cleardb database

Tags: git, heroku, cleardb

I've been testing my routes in postman through my heroku url by adding posts and users. But everytime I find an error, fix it, and push to heroku again it empties out my cleardb database. I use my getmapping route and it just returns an empty array. I'm worried about this because what if I get this up and running and it starts getting real users and post but I find an error, then if I push to heroku it will clear them out.

I'm using spring boot for my api and cleardb add-on from heroku.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. In my application.properties I had 
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` 
instead it needed to be:
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`